# How can I use winston.transports.File with react?

Tags: reactjs, winston

How can I use winston.transports.File with react?

**

> `Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function`

**

Answer (score 0):

If you are running React in node.js then this will be fine. If you are running React in the browser then your code does not have access to the file system to be able to write a file, so you cannot use `winston.transports.File`.